# Error while creating react native app in vs code

Tags: react-native, expo, npm-audit

```sh
PS D:\Coding Projects\Drinking Water Reminder App> npx create-expo-app Aqua
√ Downloaded and extracted project files.
npm install
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.

added 1159 packages, and audited 1160 packages in 4m

65 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

✅ Your project is ready!

To run your project, navigate to the directory and run one of the following npm commands.

- cd Aqua
- npm run android
- npm run ios # you need to use macOS to build the iOS project - use the Expo app if you need to do iOS development without a Mac
- npm run web
```

I tried re creating, but got this error message

Comment: I don't see any error messages. What's unclear about _"✅ Your project is ready!"_?

Comment: "5 moderate severity vulnerabilities". Also, I i get errors when I run command "npm run android"

Comment: It's not an error. You can probably just ignore them. If you're really concerned, did you try running `npm audit fix` as suggested? If you want it fixed, you need to raise an issue with the packages requiring those dependencies

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do I need android sdk installed, if I want to work with React native Expo

Comment: You will need android sdk if you want to run android simulator